# How to make 2 on_member work events with the same decorator?

Tags: python, discord.py

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    global welcome_channel_dict
    global autoroles
    channel_id = welcome_channel_dict[str(member.guild.id)]
    embed=discord.Embed(colour=discord.Colour.green())    
    embed=discord.Embed(title="<:memberjoined:778987095837769759> Member Joined", color=0x2ECC71, description=f'{member.mention} joined **{member.guild}**! Enjoy your stay!  :tada:')
    embed.set_thumbnail(url=member.avatar_url)    
    await client.get_channel(channel_id).send(embed=embed)
    
    role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, id=autoroles[str(member.guild.id)]) 

    await member.add_roles(role)
```

**What I'm trying to achieve:** Now the `autorole` only works when people ***also*** enabled the welcome messages. And I want it to work separately.

Answer (score 1):

Your client should be of `Bot` class

```py
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
client = Bot(command_prefix="!")
```

later in code

```py
async def on_member_join(member):
    #do_some_stuff

client.add_listener(on_member_join)

async def on_member_join(member):
    #do_some_more_stuff

client.add_listener(on_member_join)
```

Comment: So i can do the welcome message in the upper one and the autorole in the bottom one?

Comment: @Rensjuh Two functions work separately so there would be no problem

Comment: When i do that it says function already defined https://pastebin.com/ScexdMkg

Comment: You have @client.event() on top of on_member_join. Delete it